# Error installing Nokogiri on macOS Sierra

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-5, railsapps

Am trying to install Nokogiri on Sierra, and get an error message which tells me to check the mkmf.log. What do I need to do to get Nokogiri to install correctly?Here are the contents of the mkmf.log file:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe    -Werror -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"gcc -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future   -Werror -c conftest.c"
error: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

have_header: checking for iconv.h... -------------------- yes

"gcc -E -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <iconv.h>
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for gzdopen() in -lz... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.3.0 -lz  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <zlib.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     printf("%p", &t);
11:   }
12: 
13:   return 0;
14: }
15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))gzdopen; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_iconv?: checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-d220a5.o
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-d220a5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <stdlib.h>
 4: #include <iconv.h>
 5: 
 6: int main(void)
 7: {
 8:     iconv_t cd = iconv_open("", "");
 9:     iconv(cd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
10:     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
11: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.3.0 -liconv -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <stdlib.h>
 4: #include <iconv.h>
 5: 
 6: int main(void)
 7: {
 8:     iconv_t cd = iconv_open("", "");
 9:     iconv(cd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
10:     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
11: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Probably relevant: [Nokogiri issue #1258](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1258).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command in the terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

That fixed it for me when Nokogiri failed to install.